# Searching By Starting Letter in Lambda

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda

I want to set a button that when i press it , it will take the string in a Textbox and find all records on a **Certain Feild** on a Data Table that starts by this string or char.
And then show result in a Listbox or DataGridViewer

here is the little bit of code i've achieved , but i can't continue it

```
   private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyLinqDataContext MyData = new MyLinqDataContext();
        MyList myLambda =  MyData.MyLists.First(lambda => lambda.First_Name.StartsWith(TxtFirstName.Text));

    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well how does that not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `First` in linq, returns a single record.  you will want to use `Where` to return a list.

2) `Where` in linq will return a collection of type `IEnumerable<T>`.  You will either need to call `.ToList()` on it afterwards, or use `var` as the type.

3) You shouldn't need to create a new data context to run this against, as long as you have the original table in a queryable format.

final code, by example

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myLambda =  MyDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(lambda => lambda.Field<string>("First_Name").StartsWith(TxtFirstName.Text));
    //var should be of the type IEnumerable<DataRow>

    //from here, we can use this var as the DataSource for another display
    resultsBox.DataSource = myLambda;
    //assuming resultsBox can interpret a datarow correctly.  
    //You may need to select First_Name only, or some other data, out of the returned values.
}
```

Alternatively, using the data context

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyLinqDataContext MyData = new MyLinqDataContext();
    var myLambda =  MyData.MyLists.Where(lambda => lambda.First_Name.StartsWith(TxtFirstName.Text));

    resultsBox.DataSource = myLambda;
}
```

Comment: Best Explained for me , Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all records you don't want to use `.First()` you want to use `.Where()` so

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyLinqDataContext MyData = new MyLinqDataContext();
    MyList myLambda =  MyData.MyLists.Where(lambda => lambda.First_Name.StartsWith(TxtFirstName.Text[0].ToString()));
}
```

The above uses the first index of the string [0] to retrieve the first character.